# Glyphicons not aligning properly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I am trying to make a page that shows an Application, the Environments that app is served in (Dev, Test, Prod, etc), and finally the Host that application is running on.

In our back-end, we have it set up so that an application can be made active or passive, and a host can be made active or passive as well. I've added glyphicons that visualize the app and host states.

The glyphicons are supposed to be contained within the server name button, and if you run the jsfiddle in Chrome you'll see how it's supposed to look.

The problem is in Firefox, the glyphicons get pushed down to what looks like a new line. I don't want this to happen - I want it to look the same as in Chrome. I've done some googling and inspecting of properties and can't see to ascertain why this is happening and how it can be fixed.

```
<body>
<div id="container" class="container-fluid col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12" role="main">
  <div class="app row" id="ATStatsProcessor">
    <h4>Application Name</h4>
    <div class="environment col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
      <h5>Environment Name</h5>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
      <div class="host">
        <div class="host btn btn-default btn-pressed">
          <span class="button-text">Server Name</span>
          <span class="state-enabled icon-size-small glyphicon glyphicon-off pull-right"></span>
          <span class="state-enabled icon-size-small glyphicon glyphicon-hdd pull-right"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.app {
    color: #818a98;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #e4e9ef;
}

div.environment h5 {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 80%;
}

.environment {
    color: #818a98;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: .5em 2.25em;
    padding-top: .25em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    background-color: white;
}

.app .environment .host {
    display: inherit;
    margin: .25em;
}

.host.btn.btn-default {
    background-color: #c93135;
    color: white;
}

.host.btn.btn-pressed {
    background-color: #2f3b46;
    color: white;
}

.confirm.btn-success {
    background-color: #63a72c !important;
}

.confirm.btn-danger {
    background-color: #c93135 !important;
}

body {
    background-color: #f8f9fb !important;
}

.icon-size-small {
    font-size: x-small;
}

.state-enabled {
        color: green;
    }

    .button-text {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 85%;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zc419hwa/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that floats clear all elements within a parent element that has the `white-space: nowrap;` property in Firefox. Not sure why this is, but it can be worked around easily enough.  You can fix the issue a few different ways:

Modify your HTML code by moving the button-text span after the glyphicons like so:

```
<div class="host btn btn-default btn-pressed">
    <span class="state-enabled icon-size-small glyphicon glyphicon-off pull-right"></span>
    <span class="state-enabled icon-size-small glyphicon glyphicon-hdd pull-right"></span>
    <span class="button-text">Server Name</span>
</div>
```

--OR--

Remove property `white-space: nowrap;` from your `.btn` class.

--OR--

Absolutely position your glyphicons by adding this code to your CSS:

```
.host {
  position: relative;
}

.host .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.host .glyphicon-hdd {
  margin-right: 21px;
}
```

Comment: Moving the server name span to after the glyphicons worked. Could you explain why that worked though?

Comment: It appears that floats are clearing elements with the `white-space: nowrap;` property in Firefox.  Not sure why this is.

Comment: Actually, after playing with this in my own JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bdhmjbk1/ I discovered that it's the parent element's `white-space: nowrap` property that is causing the issue.  Floated elements are clearing any element with a parent that has `white-space: nowrap`.